# Событие на родительский блок

Tags: html

Есть обычный блок div, а в нем еще несколько блоков. В дочерних блоках написан текст и т.п.

Нужно при клике на родительский блок, что бы она исчезла.

Например:

```
<div id="main" style="width: 400px; height: 400px; background: lime;" onDblClick="this.style.display = 'none';">
     <div style="background: red;">Text1 text1 text1 ...</div>
     <div style="background: blue;">Text2 text2 text2 ...</div>
</div>
```

Все работает, но если кликнуть на дочерние блоки, то всеравно скроется блок. Как сделать что бы это было, только при нажатии на "main" блок ?

Answer (score 1):

примерно так:

```
$('#main').dblclick(function(e) {
    if (e.target.id === "main"){
        this.style.display = 'none'; 
    }
});
```

ну или на чистом js:

```
document.getElementById('main').ondblclick = 
    function(e) {
        if (e.target.id === "main"){
            this.style.display = 'none'; 
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

У объекта `event`, который передаётся в обработчик, есть свойство `target`, в котором хранится элемент, вызвавший событие. Вам нужно проверить, является ли `target` события родительским дивом, и если нет, отменить обработку события.